# Get percentage by dividing two columns from sum(case) statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, aggregate

Im trying to add the results of two columns and also do a calculation based on a total column to the "on time" column in my query below.  What i want as a result is these columns:

Appraiser 'OntimeSum' 'PastDueSum' 'Ontime + pastdue' '%ontime'

I already have the first three in the query below but i dont know how to do the others and cant seem to figure them out or find examples anywhere.

```
WITH AppraiserTurnTime AS
(SELECT (v.ContactLastName+ ', ' +v.ContactFirstName) AS Appraiser

   ,SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate <= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OnTime
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate >= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PastDue


FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
JOIN VendorClasses vc ON vc.VendorClassID = v.VendorClassID

WHERE vc.VendorClassID in (6, 3)
GROUP BY ContactFirstName,v.ContactLastName)

SELECT * FROM AppraiserTurnTime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much got it.

```
(2)   ,SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate <= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OnTime
(3)   ,SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate >= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PastDue
```

Total will be (2)+(3),  % ontime will be (2)/((2)+(3))

You can either insert the queries for (2) and (3) above for each metric, or if you want, create a nested query so you can reference the columns i.e.

```
SELECT ..., OnTime+PastDue, etc.
FROM ( your original query)
```

Also, the current query will overcount because you're using both >= and <=.  It would be good to decide whether something that happens at the exact time is overdue or not.

Comment: thanks i got the total to work but ran into a divide by 0 problem on the other. tried to solve by using this but all this returns is 0 in every row.

Comment: (SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate <= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/NULLIF(
 (SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate <= oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
 ( SUM(CASE WHEN oi.SubmittedDate > oi.AssignedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), 0) AS Percentage